# Custom appengine logins

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building an app which should allow any user to setup and account using any email address. app-engine seems to only accept gmail.com addresses. is what i want to do possible and if so can anyone point me in the right direction? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard App Engine [users API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) supports any Google account. Google accounts can be on any domain, not just gmail.com - here's the [create an account](http://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount) form. App Engine also supports OpenID, which allows users to sign in using any valid OpenID provider.

If you insist on developing your own login system, that's possible too - you'll need to use a session library such as [Beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/) to keep track of users once they're logged in. I'd counsel against it, though - it's a lot of work to get right, and requires your users to sign up to yet another account, instead of being able to use their existing accounts as OpenID and Google Accounts do.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Nick. Of all the wheels that can be laboriously and pointlessly reinvented, a login system will yield the smallest gains while providing the greatest chance to have your application's integrity compromised.

Comment: How do you think this applies when you are creating an Android app and the user can just click play and then he has a user in the server and his data is now there?